# How to connect $x$, $y$ component of 2D electromagnetic wave equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I want to solve following Maxwell's equation.
$$
\triangledown ^{2}E+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}E=0
$$
But, Electric field has x, y component in 2D geometry.
So, it will be
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} E_x}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2} E_x}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}E_x=0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} E_y}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^{2} E_y}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\omega^{2}}{c^{2}}E_y=0
$$
They are perfectly separated, so if I put a y-directional source Jy on a surface.
It seems that it wouldn't affect to Ex.
So, Ex in all domain would be 0, but it isn't in real.
Could you tell me what is worng?

Comment: you also have to consider that in the absence of charges divE=0 (you have a sign error in the equation)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I modified the sign.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions? The equations have infinitely many solutions if you don't specify them.

Comment: The boundary condition is n x E = 0 on conductor surface, and source is Jy on a boundary.